# Backface visibility CSS envelope animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an envelope opening animation with transparent images. The flap is set up to open with the `swing-top-fwd` animation from [animista.net](http://animista.net). That works, to some degree: the flap swings open. But the inside of the flap doesn't render properly. It's made of two images, a front (or outside) and back (or inside). I'm trying to use CSS `backface-visibility` to make the inside appear on top of the outside when the envelope is in the open state. This is the part that doesn't work. On Chrome it works... kinda - the back appears on top, but only after the animation finishes. It doesn't animate with the rest of the flap. On Firefox and IE, it doesn't work at all. [Here it is in action](https://mycowabungas.com/data/img/invitations/envelope/env.htm).

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Open Envelope" onclick="document.getElementById('flap').className='swing-top-fwd';">
<div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;margin-top:300px;">
    <img src="envelope-base.png">
    <div id="flap">
        <img src="flap-open.png" style="" class="back open">
        <img src="flap-closed.png" class="front closed">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes swing-top-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0);transform:rotateX(0);-webkit-transform-origin:top;transform-origin:top}100%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);transform:rotateX(180deg);-webkit-transform-origin:top;transform-origin:top}}@keyframes swing-top-fwd{0%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(0);transform:rotateX(0);-webkit-transform-origin:top;transform-origin:top}100%{-webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);transform:rotateX(180deg);-webkit-transform-origin:top;transform-origin:top}}
.swing-top-fwd {
    -webkit-animation: swing-top-fwd 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    -moz-animation: swing-top-fwd 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: swing-top-fwd 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

.swing-top-fwd-reverse {
    -webkit-animation: swing-top-fwd 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) reverse both;
    -moz-animation: swing-top-fwd 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) reverse both;
    animation: swing-top-fwd 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) reverse both;
}

#flap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

#flap .open {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#flap .closed {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `z-index` is confusing. What I believe you need to do is flip the inside of the envelope flap, so that it shows when the flap is flipped. That sentence sounds funny. Anyway.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Justastudent/754wp10f/1/) first, details later.

```js
var flap = document.getElementById('flap');
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (!flap.classList.contains('swing-top-fwd')) {
  flap.classList.add('swing-top-fwd');
  } else {
    flap.classList.toggle('reverse');
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes swing-top-fwd {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swing-top-fwd-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  
  100%{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

.swing-top-fwd {
    animation-name: swing-top-fwd;
}
.swing-top-fwd.reverse {
    animation-name: swing-top-fwd-reverse;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 405px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#flap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    transform-origin: top;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#flap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#flap img.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Toggle Envelope" id="toggle" />
<div id="container">
    <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Mwf.png">
    <div id="flap">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9LGl.png" class="back">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO2BZ.png" class="front">
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>I have taken the liberty of uploading your images to [StackOverflow's Imgur](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/), for the sake of preservation of this question.</sub>

The idea is that we rotate the back of the envelope flap 180 degrees. Both the front and back of the flap get `backface-visibility: none;` so that in the initial state, only the front of the flap is visible. We then rotate the entire flap in the animation, which will make it so that the front of the envelope flap is gradually shown.

Since browser support is good for [transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) and [animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), I dropped all the vendor prefixes you had. Then I changed your button into one that toggles the state of the envelope, just for testing. I also cleaned up the markup a bit and extracted the JavaScript from the HTML, but those are minor changes. The major ideas are:

•  `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the images in the `#flap`;
•  `transform: rotateY(180deg);` on the inside of the flap;
•  animation on the `rotateX` transformation of the flap itself.

Finally, I set a [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) on the container element. This improves the look of the animation, as it becomes actually 3D. You can of course tweak this to change the effect.

This works for me in Firefox on Linux. In Chrome, the animation stutters the first time I toggle it, but then works smoothly after. I attempted to remedy that in multiple ways, but did not succeed. This I believe is a local problem, so it should work in all major modern browsers.

Comment: This is excellent - it does seem to work much better, except for the Chrome issue. It seems I can "solve" that by hiding the envelope off the screen, running the animation once, and then moving the envelope back in to view before running the animation "for real".

Comment: @D.Strout That is something I had not tried yet, but should work. If that is acceptable for your use case of course. Would you like me to implement that and add it to my answer?

Comment: Nah, I can do that by myself. I'm going to implement your solution, make sure it works, and then award the bounty. But that will be tomorrow.

Comment: @D.Strout Sure thing! Let me know if there is anything that is broken or needs clarification, I'd be happy to update my answer.

Comment: Got it all set up, and it works well. Thanks again for the help.